# Cannot assign value of type 'Array<SKtexture>' to type 'SKTexture'

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I define a array of SKTextures in a class like this :

```
var walking: Array<SKTexture> = []
```

Then I have a function in the same class that returns a element of that array :

```
func running() -> SKTexture{
    self.counter_run += self.counter_run
    if (self.counter_run >= 2){
        self.counter_run = 0
    }
    return self.walking[counter_run]
}
```

And I use that function in an other part of my code in order to animate my character :

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    player.texture = koopa.walking()
}
```

But I get this error :

```
Cannot assign value of type 'Array<SKtexture>' to type 'SKTexture'
```

Comment: You probably mean `player.texture = koopa.running()`. Run, not walk.

Comment: Thanks I didn't realise that I did that

Comment: Vadian thank you that mended it

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to assign an the array `walking` to the nodes texture, which is of type `SKTexture`.

Depending on what you want to achieve set one texture of `walking` to the node:

```
player.texture = walking[counter_run]
```

or use an action:

```
player.runAction(SKAction.animateWithTextures(walking, timePerFrame: 0.5))
```

---

Edit:
The texture animation of your approach depends on the frame rate, which you most probably do not want. Thus I recommend to use the later.

Comment: @OliverRedeyoff I would go with SKAction in this case. Why reinventing a wheel...